# REST Assured: missing class that's (apparently) not missing

Tags: java, rest, exception, rest-assured

Here's my simple code:

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.get;

public class testget {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Response countryName = get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=45.2542285874,30.2564857&sensor=false");
        System.out.println(countryName);
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

When running, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/restassured/mapper/factory/ObjectMapperFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.jayway.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig.<init>(RestAssuredConfig.java:41)
at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:423)
    at testeget.main(testeget.java:6)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayway.restassured.mapper.factory.ObjectMapperFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
```

But the Rest Assured lib is loaded, otherwise the get method wouldn't even be called... What could it be?

I'm using Rest Assured 2.8.

Update:

I'm using Eclipse to run it, and the classpath has, besides the default Java/Eclipse content, the path to the .jar file of Rest Assured and it's dependencies, as listed on their website.

Dependencies list on the bottom of the page (all added to the classpath).

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/2.8.0

Comment: how do you run your application? What is on the classpath?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse to run it, and the classpath has, besides the default Java/Eclipse content, the path to the .jar file of Rest Assured and it's dependencies, as listed on their website.

Comment: What version of the lib was used to compile?  What version is used when running?

Comment: Both REST Assured 2.8.

Comment: That class is not in the restassured jar.  There is no 'factory' package under 'mapper'.  So just because get is loaded doesn't mean this other class is.  I didn't see anything in the dependency list that would seem to be an obvious jar for it to be in.  Do you know where that class is located?